# yq expression to get specific output

Tags: string, bash, yaml, yq

Could you please help with expression for **yq** on bash to get specific output from file?

I have instance.yaml file

```yaml
- instances:
  - um
  - ume
  - umd
  - mon
  - wtn
  - tm
  - tq
  sleep: 15
- instances:
  - or
  - rd
  sleep: 45
- instances:
  - sat
  - sor
  sleep: 30
- instances:
  - ab
  - at
  - bs
  - cs
  - hd
  - it
  - md
  - mdk
  - mpa
  - pk
  - qs
  - vm
  sleep: 20
- instances:
  - es
  sleep: 5
```

And I want to get in the output something like this:

```bash
UM=15, UME=15, UMD=15, MON=15, WTN=15, TM=15, TQ=15
OR=45, RD=45
SAT=30, SOR=30
AB=20, AT=20, BS=20, CS=20, HD=20, IT=20, MD=20, MDK=20, MPA=20, PK=20, QS=20, VM=20
ES=5
```

Currently I'm using this code, but it should be changed because it doesn't contain `sleep` value

```bash
yq 'to_entries | .[] | .value.instances | join(", ") | upcase' instance.yml
```

Current output:

```bash
UM, UME, UMD, MON, WTN, TM, TQ
OR, RD
SAT, SOR
AS, AT, BS, CS, HD, IT, MD, MDK, MPA, PK, QS, VM
ES
```

In the general case, I want to create a dictionary from the retrieved strings. Perhaps there is another, most simple solution....

Comment: Which version of `yq` are you using?

Comment: Hello @Paolo, yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.35.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.[] | [ (.instances[] | upcase) + "=" + .sleep ] | join(", ")
```

Will output

```
UM=15, UME=15, UMD=15, MON=15, WTN=15, TM=15, TQ=15
OR=45, RD=45
SAT=30, SOR=30
AB=20, AT=20, BS=20, CS=20, HD=20, IT=20, MD=20, MDK=20, MPA=20, PK=20, QS=20, VM=20
ES=5
```